# Adding API 27 support in Android project producing error

Tags: java, android

I recently upgraded Android studio and added support for API level 27. Created an emulator for API 27 (pixel xl).

The app runs perfectly fine on Nexus 5X emulator, but fails with following error on Pixel XL emulator. Can someone guide me with right direction?\

Error:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.localhost.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mycompany.myapp.activity.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.localhost.myapp-fwgWxCeG6fwAPqPFcI0DsA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.localhost.myapp-fwgWxCeG6fwAPqPFcI0DsA==/split_lib_directories_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.localhost.myapp-fwgWxCeG6fwAPqPFcI0DsA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.localhost.myapp-fwgWxCeG6fwAPqPFcI0DsA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]`

Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.localhost.myapp'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.0.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
    productFlavors {
        localhost {
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.getBuildType().getName() == 'release') {
            variant.assemble.doLast {
                copy {
                    from variant.mappingFile
                    into "proguard"
                    rename { String fileName ->
                        "mapping-${variant.name}.txt"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def flavors = []

new File("app/flavors").eachFile() { file ->

    def fileName = file.getName()

    if (fileName.endsWith('.gradle')) {
        flavors.push(fileName)
    }
}

flavors.each { flavorName ->
    apply from: rootProject.file("app/flavors/$flavorName")
}

greendao {
    schemaVersion 1
    targetGenDir "src/main/java"
    daoPackage "com.mycompany.myapp.dao"
}

dependencies {
    ext {
        supportLibVersion = '27.1.0'
    }
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':aFileChooser')
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:${supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:richeditor-android:1.2.2'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.2'
    implementation 'org.sufficientlysecure:html-textview:3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I tried `multiDexEnabled true` but that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of investigation, I found the "Instant Run" feature is causing the issue. If I disable Instant Run from Android Studio settings, the app is deployed with all source classes.

The side effect is the debugger cannot detect the classes and I cannot debug by placing debug points. If someone has any other solution, I am glad to see that.